# Why won't my @Font-Faces load?

Tags: css, font-face, webfonts, font-family

My fonts won't appear on my website and I don't know why! The only reason I could really think of is that perhaps I was loading in too many? However, I tried removing a load of them and this did not appear the case. Any ideas?

The code...

```css
#panel1 h1 {
 color: #e66854;
 font-family: MuseoSansRounded500, helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size:30px;
}


@font-face {
    font-family: MuseoSansRounded100;
    src:url(fonts/MUSEOSANSROUNDED-100_0.OTF);
 
 font-family: MuseoSansRounded300;
 src:url(fonts/MUSEOSANSROUNDED-300_0.OTF);
 
 font-family: MuseoSansRounded500;
 src:url(fonts/MUSEOSANSROUNDED-500_0.OTF);
 
 font-family: OpenSansLight;
 src:url(fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf);
 
 font-family: OpenSansLightItalic;
 src:url(fonts/OpenSans-LightItalic.ttf);
 
 font-family: OpenSansReg;
 src:url(fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf);
 
 font-family: OpenSansRegItalic;
 src:url(fonts/OpenSans-Italic.ttf);
 
 font-family: OpenSansSemiBold;
 src:url(fonts/OpenSans-Semibold.ttf);
 
 font-family: OpenSansSemiBoldItalic;
 src:url(fonts/OpenSans-SemiboldItalic.ttf);
 
 font-family: OpenSansBold;
 src:url(fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf);
 
 font-family: OpenSansBoldItalic;
 src:url(fonts/OpenSans-BoldItalic.ttf);
}
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions! :)

Comment: Is the fonts folder inside you CSS folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split each font declaration into separate @font-face blocks

```
@font-face {
   font-family: MuseoSansRounded100;
   src:url(fonts/MUSEOSANSROUNDED-100_0.OTF);
}
@font-face {
   font-family: MuseoSansRounded300;
   src:url(fonts/MUSEOSANSROUNDED-300_0.OTF);
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

One technique that's worked for me is adding the format at the end:

```
src: url(fonts/MUSEOSANSROUNDED-300_0.OTF) format('opentype');
```